# Maven: dynamic specification of dependencies

Tags: maven-3

I have started to learn Maven and have the following question:

I would like to dynamically specify a dependency for building maven project instead of using the dependency specified in POMs - is there a way to do that?

So although I have the following dependencies specified in POM

```
...
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectComponent</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
...
```

I would like to specify in the build command that I want to use a different version.
Is there a way to specify this?

The idea is that I want to have an integration build made in Jenkins with a dependency on the latest available snapshot of the system for a particular branch. That snapshot is not released to the maven repository yet, so I would like to fetch it in Jenkins and specify a dependency for mvn build.

Thanks!

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**: What I ended up with is to use ${my.lib.version} construction and specify it with -Dmy.lib.version=1.0-SNAPSHOT" when calling to mvn. Thus I can use it for Jenkins integration builds by fetching arbitrary snapshot versions of dependencies from svn and feeding their snapshot versions to the integration build pom.

Comment: What is your intention to have a dynamic dependency? Can you explain that a little bit more?

Comment: @khmarbaise The idea is that I want to have an integration build made in Jenkins with a dependency on the latest available snapshot of the system for a particular branch. That snapshot is not released to the maven repository yet, so I would like to fetch it in Jenkins and specify a dependency for mvn build.

Comment: The best solution is to use SNAPSHOT versions for exactly such purpose.

Comment: @khmarbaise that was my initial idea as well, however I am not able to update the pom's dependency to the SNAPSHOT version if it is not released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up with is to use ${my.lib.version} construction and specify it with -Dmy.lib.version=1.0-SNAPSHOT" when calling to mvn. Thus I can use it for Jenkins integration builds by fetching arbitrary snapshot versions of dependencies from svn and feeding their snapshot versions to the integration build pom.

Answer (score 3):

Maven may use "dynamically" specified property (ex: *group.ProjectComponent.version*) with the help of profiles.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectComponent</artifactId>
    <version>${group.ProjectComponent.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

So if you create some profiles you may switch between them (see maven references)

Example:

```
<profile>
    <id>stable-builds</id>
    <properties>
        <group.ProjectComponent.version>1.0</group.ProjectComponent.version>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>beta-builds</id>
    <properties>
        <group.ProjectComponent.version>2.0.Beta1</group.ProjectComponent.version>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you by any chance know if there is a way to provide a value for the dependency to mvn from a command line? Or it would require messing up the poms?

Comment: pass the system property "mvn clean test -Dmy.lib.version=1.0-SNAPSHOT" Although you can do this, it could be bad idea as its easy to force the project to use arbitrary version of the dependency by simply overriding this property.

Comment: @Kal Thanks, thats exactly what I have decided to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this as I was looking for something similar.  In my case same application code is being reused on different stacks which means using different "drivers" for accessing data.  Although drivers implement same interface they do come from different artifacts.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't change the dependencies dynamically. Furthermore it does not make sense, cause you would like to have a reproducible build.

Comment: actually you can, you can specify it like -Dmy.lib.version=1.0-SNAPSHOT" (as suggested) if you have a dependency in the pom written as ${my.lib.version}

Comment: Which will make your build not reproducible. Which is in my opinion a no-go.

Comment: @khmarbaise is there a way of defining different versions of dependency for different branches of project, e.g use model-prod-v1 for master branch, use model-dev-v1 for dev